# What is the recommended way to sum a list in TorchScript

Tags: pytorch, jit

Because `Python builtin <built-in function sum> is currently not supported in Torchscript:` I'm looking for the recommended way to do something like:

```py
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def forward(self, x):
        return sum(x.tolist())

model = Model()   
model = torch.jit.script(model)     
model(torch.arange(10))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest approach would be to use PyTorch's `sum` directly:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.sum(x)
```

If, for some reason, this is not an option, you have to use type specification with explicit loop (**please notice type hints!**):

```
import typing

import torch
import torch.nn as nn


class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def forward(self, x) -> int:
        x: typing.List[int] = x.tolist()
        result = 0
        for elem in x:
            result += elem
        return result
```

Comment: Thanks. I had a list from earlier on in the method so that's why I didn't immediately go for `torch.sum`. I ended up doing it anyway, converting the list to a tensor then using `Tensor.item()` as I needed an `int`.